# How does control flow back to statements before render_template in flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I don't clearly understand how the form validation occurs on submit. When the index function is called, the `if form.validate_on_submit` will
initially be false right? So it should return the rendered template. But only the object '`form`' is passed to the rendered template, so after returning the rendered template, how will the control flow back to the if statement? (`if form.validate_on_submit`)

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

if form.validate_on_submit():
  blah blah blah I do something......
  return redirect(url_for('index'))

return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

Comment: it will not flow back. It sends form to browser and it finish this function. When user clicks button in form in browser then browser sends form to server (flask), server (flask) gets form as new request and it runs `index()` again. And then it runs again `if form.validate_on_submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't go back directly. It sends form to browser and it finishs this function (and it forgets current client - it disconnects this user). When user clicks button in form in browser then browser has to connect again with server (flask), sends new requests to `/upload` with form to server (flask), server (flask) gets form as new request and it runs `index()` again. And then it runs again `if form.validate_on_submit` again.

---

Maybe if you would have to learn `socket` and use it to build server from scratch then you would see how it works :)

Answer (score -1):

`validate_on_submit` is used **after** submitting your form. Your code should be along the line of:

```py
  @app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':   
      if form.validate_on_submit():
        blah blah blah I do something......
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

  return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But I still don't understand this, because at first the HTML file should be rendered right? and for that the control should reach `return render_template('upload.html',form=form)` right? So after rendering, if we press the submit button on the browser how can the control go back to `if form.validate_on_submit()` because that part of the code is already over and out of scope?